# Is it OK to use QuerySet.update() instead of object.save() in ModelAdmin.save_model()

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have pretty standard save_model() override, which computes some values and at the end calls object.save()

I'm rewriting the application for better scalability and read that .save() is not thread safe and doesn't allow for data partitioning. The recommended best practice is to use update().

My question is: is it OK if I do an update() instead of save() in save_model()? I don't see any downsides of it, do you?

Answer (score 0):

I think the warning in the docs about [updating multiple objects at once](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) is relevant. If you're not using any signals, overriding the model's save method, or using the `auto_now` field option, I can't think of any other potential problems.

> Be aware that the `update()` method is converted directly to an SQL statement. It is a bulk operation for direct updates. It doesn't run any `save()` methods on your models, or emit the `pre_save` or `post_save` signals (which are a consequence of calling `save()`), or honor the `auto_now` field option. If you want to save every item in a `QuerySet` and make sure that the `save()` method is called on each instance, you don't need any special function to handle that. Just loop over them and call `save()`:

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Alasdair. I'm not using any signals and I'm not overriding the model's save() method. Plus I will be updating only one object based on PK. I will give it a try.